# Typing conditional properties with union

Tags: flowtype

I have the following method defined on a custom `Component` ES6 class which takes an object with a `component` property. If that property is an instance of `Component` it assigns it to `ref` else it creates a new instance with the `el` and `opts` properties :

```
setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
    let ref: Component;

    if (component instanceof Component) { 
         ref = component
    } else {
        ref = new component(el, opts);
    }
}
```

My type definitions for `refConstructorType` and `refInstanceType` are:

```
type refInstanceType = {|
    component: Component,
    id: string,
    props?: {}
|};

type refConstructorType = {|
    component: typeof Component,
    id: string,
    el: Element,
    opts ?: {[option_ke: string]: string},
    props ?: {}
|};
```

Anyway flowtype is complaining:

```
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                    ^^^^^^^^^ Component. This type is incompatible with
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                    ^^^^^^^^^ class type: Component

src/index.js:86
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                    ^^^^^^^^^ class type: Component. This type is incompatible with
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                    ^^^^^^^^^ Component

src/index.js:86
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                                ^^ property `el`. Property not found in
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type

src/index.js:86
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                                    ^^^^ property `opts`. Property not found in
86:     setRef({ id, component, el, opts = {}, props = {} }: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {
                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
```

Any hint on how to solve this?

#### Update 26/07/2017

Following the suggested pattern I ended up with the following refined code:

```
setRef(refCfg: refConstructorType | refInstanceType): Promise<Component> {

    let ref: Component;

    if (!isPlainObject(refCfg)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid reference configuration');
    }

    if (refCfg.component instanceof Component) {
        ref = refCfg.component;
    } else if (typeof refCfg.component === 'function' && refCfg.el) {
        const { el, opts, component } = refCfg;
        ref = new component(el, opts); //eslint-disable-line new-cap
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid reference configuration');
    }
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty complex situation, but the safe way to get around this is to not de-structure.

You're putting Flow in a position where you're asking it to create a variable `component` with type `Component | typeof Component` and asking if that union type is valid against the `refConstructorType.component` and valid against the `refInstanceType.component`:

- `Component == Component | typeof Component`?
- `typeof Component == Component | typeof Component`?

Basically, with destructuring, it implicitly fails "one in, all out": https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-union-types-requires-one-in-but-all-out.

That's why you're seeing Flow complain about it twice.

Once you fix that, the other errors are most likely going to be solved by making sure Flow can accurately discriminate between the different conditions in your if/else.

Comment: I've updated the question with the working code based on your suggestions. Thank you!